# How to create token for unit test on Solana

Tags: solana, solana-web3js, anchor-solana

I'm trying to create token/nft for testing my transfer method in unit test.
Here is my code:

```
    const connection = new Connection("https://api.devnet.solana.com");
    const myKeypair = web3.Keypair.generate();
    const fromAirdropSignature = await connection.requestAirdrop(myKeypair.publicKey, 2 * anchor.web3.LAMPORTS_PER_SOL);
    await connection.confirmTransaction(fromAirdropSignature);
    let minter = await splToken.createMint(connection, myKeypair, myKeypair.publicKey, null, 1, web3.Keypair.generate(), null, splToken.TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID)
```

I tried this way but when I run anchor test, sometimes requestAirdrop doesn't work. Is this the right way to do? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3):

When using devnet, you will always be limited in how much you can airdrop. You can get around that by doing one airdrop and reusing the same `myKeypair` for all of your test runs.

The best environment for unit tests, however, is a local `solana-test-validator`, which has higher limits for airdrops, and can be destroyed / recreated anytime.

Before running your tests, in a separate shell, you can run:

```
$ solana-test-validator -r
```

And then connect to it using:

```
const connection = new Connection("http://localhost:8899");
```

Comment: If you run solana-test-validator -r, you have to use anchor run test or anchor test --skip-local-validator. There's another way is just connect to local and run anchor test. But it seems run unittest on local takes more time than run on devnet

Comment: That's right, `anchor test` will spin up the validator for you, which makes things easier. And it's possible that it's slower since you have to start the validator and wait a second or two for fees to stabilize on the test network